# how to push notification in China?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

I'm working with react-native in Hong Kong but my target country is China.
I need to handle push notifications in China
Anyway, can help me push notifications for Android and Huawei without GCM?
Thanks everybody!

Comment: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/service-introduction-0000001050040060

Comment: Though google are blocked in china, firebase indeed have some services

Accords https://firebase.google.cn/products/extensions, you can send with messageBird api

Comment: You can use any firebase alternative available from China like parseplatform.org . https://launch-in-china.21yunbox.com/solutions/firebase-alternatives-in-china.html

Answer (score 0):

As @[gbalduzzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4861873/gbalduzzi) mentioned, you can use Huawei [push kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-pushkit?ha_source=hms1). Huawei Push Kit is a messaging service provided for you to establish a cloud-to-device messaging channel. By integrating Push Kit, you can send messages to your apps on user devices in real time. Kindly click [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/service-introduction-0000001050040060) to learn more.

Huawei also has provided some HMS Core kit plugins for React-Native:

- [Reference documents](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/overview/HMS-Core-Plugin?ha_source=hms1)
- [Push kit for React-Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Library-V1/reactnative-plugin-0000001050155850-V1)
- [Push Kit for React-Native Sample Code](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Examples/reactnative-sample-code-0000001050157811)
- [Push Kit for React-Native APIs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References/instanceid-0000001050157805)

Answer (score 0):

[Pushy](https://pushy.me/china) is a paid solution that works worldwide (including China), and is completely independent from GCM/FCM.

Full disclosure: I work at Pushy.

Alternatively, for a non-commercial solution, look into rolling out your own notification service using an MQTT or XMPP client/server setup.